# R function to sort columns of gtsummary::tbl_summary objects

Tags: r

I work with `gtsummary` package a lot and wanted to try creating a function to sort the columns of table output from `tbl_summary()` function. `tbl_summary` has a parameter `by` which is used to create multiple columns per level of a categorical variable.

An example table object is created using `trial` dataset from `gtsummary`.

```
tbl <- trial |> tbl_summary(by=stage)
tbl
```

[image]

My goal was to sort the columns in a descending order based on the numbers in `N = ...`.

#### Function Code

```
library(gtsummary)

# define a function
tbl_sort_cols <- function(tbl){
  # tbl: table object from gtsummary::tbl_summary
  # tbl object MUST include columns generated using "by" parameter in tbl_summary
  # tbl[["table_styling"]][["header"]][["label"]] has the column labels
  labs <- tbl[["table_styling"]][["header"]][["label"]]
  
  # create a list that maps labels to columns
  mapping <- list()
  
  # grab labels to sort
  labs_substr <- labs[grep(labs, pattern=".+N = ")]
  
  # assign column values to labels accordingly
  # if overall column exists (i.e. stat_0 exists), then i - 1
  # otherwise i
  if (any(grepl("Overall", labs))){
    for (i in seq_along(labs_substr)){
      mapping[[
        labs_substr[[i]]
      ]] <- tbl[["table_body"]][[paste0("stat_",(i-1))]]
    }
  } else{
    for (i in seq_along(labs_substr)){
      mapping[[
        labs_substr[[i]]
      ]] <- tbl[["table_body"]][[paste0("stat_",(i))]]
    }
  }
  
  # sort labels
  # first remove unnecessary commas
  # convert the string to numbers and sort
  processed_str <- gsub(",", "", names(mapping))
  processed_str <- as.numeric(gsub(".+N = ", "", processed_str))
  sorted_index <- order(processed_str, decreasing = T, na.last = F)
  sorted_mapping <- mapping[sorted_index]
  
  # extract indices of columns to reassign
  indices_lab <- tbl[["table_styling"]][["header"]][["label"]] |> grep("N = ", x=_)
  indices_stat <- names(tbl[["table_body"]]) |> grep("stat_", x=_)

  # reassign column labels
  tbl[["table_styling"]][["header"]][["label"]][indices_lab] <- names(sorted_mapping)

  # reassign columns
  tbl[["table_body"]][indices_stat] <- sorted_mapping

  return(tbl)
}
```

Output using the function:

```
# test, no overall
test1 <- trial |> tbl_summary(by=stage)
test1

tbl_sort_cols(test1)
```

[image]

`gtsummary` also has a function `add_overall` which adds a overall column describing summary statistics of the entire levels of the categorical variable supplied to `by` argument in `tbl_summary`. `tbl_sort_cols` also attempts to handle the case with overall column.

test output with overall column:

```
# test2, yes overall
test2 <- trial |> tbl_summary(by=stage) |> add_overall()
test2

tbl_sort_cols(test2)
```

[image]

Some datasets had more than 1,000 observations in each level. In that case `tbl_summary` generates  commas in the numbers in `N = ...`; I also attempted to handle this situation. (I've tested that with `storms` dataset and it seemed to work. Try the code below)

```
# test, arbitrary data, no overall
test3 <- dplyr::storms |> tbl_summary(by=status)
test3

tbl_sort_cols(test3)
```

I thought it might be interesting to share what I've done so far and get some feedback as well. Any comments/criticism are very welcome. Thank you